# Laravel, autocomplete using database

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do an ajax request to autocomplete the customer name, so far here's what I have:
create.index.blade

```
    <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Customer id:</strong>
              <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" name="customer_id"  placeholder="Customer id">
            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typehead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

here is my Assignee controller where the search route is:

```
use App\Customer;
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
      {
          $data = Customer::select("name")
                  ->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                  ->get();

          return response()->json($data);
      }
```

here is my routes.php

```
Route::get('autocomplete', 'AssigneeController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
```

I have a customer who's name is "test"
whenever I am typing "tes" I am not getting prompted to auto complete it with test

Comment: Okay. What's the question?

Comment: code seems correct. so what's problem?

Comment: I am not getting auto complete.. not sure how can I even debug it to check if the AJAX request is being sent.

Comment: Take a look at your Network tab in Dev Tools. Additionally, could you console.log(data) to see what kind of response you are getting?

Comment: so I am getting the following error in my Network tab:

Can't find variable: $

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the typeahead bootstrap files.
added it using the following link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
```